# How do I make a JQuery animation stay in the same place?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a pretty significant problem with my JQuery animations, lets start from the begining.
The code that I currently have is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var run = function(){
    $(".fade#f1").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
    $(".fade#f2").delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
    $(".fade#f1").delay(4000).fadeOut(1000);
    $(".fade#f2").delay(4500).fadeOut(1000);
    $(".fade#f3").delay(8000).fadeIn(1000);
    $(".fade#f4").delay(9000).fadeIn(1000);
    $(".fade#f3").delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
    $(".fade#f4").delay(5500).fadeOut(1000);
    $(".fade#f5").delay(16000).fadeIn(1000);
    $(".fade#f6").delay(17000).fadeIn(1000);
    $(".fade#f5").delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
    $(".fade#f6").delay(5000).fadeOut(1000, function() { run() }); 
};

$(document).ready(function () {
run();
});


</script>
```

My problem is that once the animation has run through once, the position where it appears on screen appears to change, I am unsure why this is set, here is the CSS code that I am using to position the first element:

```
position: absolute;
margin-left: 262px;
margin-top: 44px;
width: 400px;
```

Does anyone know why my code is doing this?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Here is the HTML

```
            <div class="fade" id="fade">
            <img src="../images/ac.png" id="f1" class="fade">
            <img src="../images/tq.png" id="f2" class="fade">
            <img src="../images/ei.png" id="f3" class="fade">
            <img src="../images/1880.png" id="f4" class="fade">
            <img src="../images/rf.png" id="f5" class="fade">
            <img src="../images/e.png" id="f6" class="fade">

        </div>
```

Comment: Can you please add your html markup also. It would be helpful.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {run();});` is the same as `$(document).ready(run);`

Comment: @doublesharp - Which is the same as `$(run);`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - good call.

Comment: Yes, please add the affected HTML. A working JSBin or CodePen always helps, too.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` change the display value.
when `fadeOut()` function calls, the elements display will set to `none`, so if you have relative elements, their position will change.
for solving this problem you should use `fadeTo()`. it use opacity instead of display. learn more [[ HERE ]](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/)

```
var run = function(){
    $(".fade#f1").delay(1000).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".fade#f2").delay(2000).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".fade#f1").delay(4000).fadeTo(1000, 0);
    $(".fade#f2").delay(4500).fadeTo(1000, 0);
    $(".fade#f3").delay(8000).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".fade#f4").delay(9000).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".fade#f3").delay(5000).fadeTo(1000, 0);
    $(".fade#f4").delay(5500).fadeTo(1000, 0);
    $(".fade#f5").delay(16000).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".fade#f6").delay(17000).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    $(".fade#f5").delay(5000).fadeTo(1000, 0);
    $(".fade#f6").delay(5000).fadeTo(1000, 0, function() { run() }); 
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works perfectly, also thanks for the link that was also really helpful :)

Comment: Your Welcome; well, if your problem is solved, you can close the question by hitting the accept tick.